# CSS menu bar to span page width

Tags: css, menu, width

I'd like the main menu from this page http://www2.gardencomedyclub.co.uk to use the entire width of the page. I've tried using `margin: 0 auto;` in varying places in the `#menu` css tags but it keeps being left justified. I'd just like the margin between the `li` elements to expand to fill the full width of the `#mainmenu` div.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Looks like your layout is fairly static, and the menu items look like they've just about filled all the available space. Why not define static widths for a few menu items to take advantage of the remaining space?

Comment: I see. So your saying either define fixed widths for the menu items or add a little defined padding/margins to flesh out the space?

Comment: I agree with Brandon.  The width of your menu won't change, so just change the margin of `#menu a` to `margin: 0 6px;`. The buttons now fit well plus they can breath a little.

Comment: I actually had that a little while ago and it all seemed to fit well when I tested in chrome, safari and all my mobile browsers. When I tested in firefox though, the `About` item was pushed onto a new line...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your #menu li remove float:left and instead use display:inline-block. This will however push the last li in a new row. To solve that, You will have to change the margin and padding for "a" as margin: 0 1px and padding: 0 1px. This works in IE9, FF4.01, GG11, AF5.0.5 and Opera 11.

Comment: Thanks very much. I was sure there would be a 'correct' way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

For `margin:0 auto;` to work, you need to set a `width`.

Use `width:730px;` on `#menu` and it should work.

Comment: It does for me.  I checked in Chrome.  Yours works as well.  Better, if he wants equal space between the items.  Mine just centers the entire list.

Comment: check again in IE9 and FF4.01