# Unable to set full page width of css menu bar

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am using this tutorial for a css menu online and it works perfectly, but it does not stretch the full width of the page: http://www.red-team-design.com/css3-animated-dropdown-menu

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

I tried changing the `width: 100%` and that helped extend it but not full width. I even did what this user did [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022036/css-menu-bar-to-span-page-width) but that did not work either. This needs to work on IE 8 as well as firefox so that is bringing up more issues there.

```
#menu, #menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 60px auto;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    background-color: #111;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444), to(#111));    
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);  
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777, 0 1px 0 #666 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777, 0 1px 0 #666 inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777, 0 1px 0 #666 inset;
}

#menu:before,
#menu:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

#menu:after {
    clear: both;
}

#menu {
    zoom:1;
}

#menu li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #222;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    position: relative;
}

#menu a {
    float: left;
    padding: 12px 30px;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}

#menu li:hover > a {
    color: #fafafa;
}

*html #menu li a:hover { /* IE6 only */
    color: #fafafa;
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    _margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;    
    background: #444;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444), to(#111));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
    background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);  
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;  
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    margin: 0;
}

#menu ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 150px;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    _margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);      
}

#menu ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    _line-height: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111, 0 2px 0 #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111, 0 2px 0 #666;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111, 0 2px 0 #666;
}

#menu ul li:last-child {   
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;    
}

#menu ul a {    
    padding: 10px;
    width: 130px;
    _height: 10px; /*IE6 only*/
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    text-transform: none;
}

#menu ul a:hover {
    background-color: #0186ba;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);  
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#04acec), to(#0186ba));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#04acec, #0186ba);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#04acec, #0186ba);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#04acec, #0186ba);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#04acec, #0186ba);
}

#menu ul li:first-child > a {
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

#menu ul li:first-child > a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: -6px;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #444;
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:after {
    left: -6px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    border-left: 0; 
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid #3b3b3b;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-bottom-color: #04acec; 
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-right-color: #0299d3; 
    border-bottom-color: transparent;   
}

#menu ul li:last-child > a {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Include the relevant code in your question. Links break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set this in your style sheet

```
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0
  padding:0;
}
```

**Why you need this** ?? because when you set the container dimension in percentage, it always looks for its parents dimension to calculate its percentage value.....

if you set `#cont` width in percentage...then `#cont` width is dependent on `body` width,**SO**, for markup

```
 <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <div id="cont">
      </div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

with

```
#cont
{
  width:80%
}
```

then it would mean that 
`#cont` = `80%` of `body`

so `#cont` would fail, if body has no width set.

Answer (score 1):

The space is because of the default margin and padding for BODY Tag.

From the comment,

Add below css

```
  body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

And also remove margin and set width to 100% in the define style #menu

```
margin: 60px auto;
width: 960px;
```

Comment: Why 0 on all elements?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the `body` has a `margin` by default.
Remove the default by adding `body { margin: 0px; }` to your CSS (and the `#menu { width: 100%; }`) of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
 Body,ul,li{margin:0;padding:0}
 #cont{
   width:100%;
   float:right;
   height:120px;
  }
```